# Trying to shorten my program so code isn't repeated

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to filter meal types into different categories using an observable collection. I'm using enums to categorise the meals, and I have three separate methods with the same code to split them into new collections when their respective buttons are clicked. The three enum types are, Vegetarian, Meat, and Fish. I have two observable collections, meals and filteredMeals. I was trying to create another method then pass down the Category as a parameter but I couldn't get it to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void btnVegetarian_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        filteredMeals = new ObservableCollection<Meal>();
        Meal newMeal = new Meal();

        for (int i = 0; i < meals.Count; i++)
        {
            newMeal = meals[i];
            if (newMeal.Category == MealCategory.Vegetarian)
            {
                filteredMeals.Add(newMeal);
            }
        }
        lbxMeals.ItemsSource = filteredMeals;
    }

    private void btnMeat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        filteredMeals = new ObservableCollection<Meal>();
        Meal newMeal = new Meal();

        for (int i = 0; i < meals.Count; i++)
        {
            newMeal = meals[i];
            if (newMeal.Category == MealCategory.Meat)
            {
                filteredMeals.Add(newMeal);
            }
        }
        lbxMeals.ItemsSource = filteredMeals;

    }

    private void btnFish_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       filteredMeals = new ObservableCollection<Meal>();
        Meal newMeal = new Meal();

        for (int i = 0; i < meals.Count; i++)
        {
            newMeal = meals[i];
            if (newMeal.Category == MealCategory.Fish)
            {
                filteredMeals.Add(newMeal);
            }
        }
        lbxMeals.ItemsSource = filteredMeals;
    }
```

Comment: Why not show the method that's not working that you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new method taking a MealCategory parameter. Move the code to there, and pass the appropiate MealCategory for each of your button click handlers.

The code could then look like this:

```
private void btnVegetarian_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterMeals(MealCategory.Vegatarian);
}

private void btnMeat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterMeals(MealCategory.Meat);
}

private void btnFish_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   FilterMeals(MealCategory.Fish);
}

private void FilterMeals(MealCategory category)
{
    filteredMeals = new ObservableCollection<Meal>();
    Meal newMeal = new Meal();

    for (int i = 0; i < meals.Count; i++)
    {
        newMeal = meals[i];
        if (newMeal.Category == category)
        {
            filteredMeals.Add(newMeal);
        }
    }
    lbxMeals.ItemsSource = filteredMeals;
}
```

Once you've got that working, you could try refactoring your FilterMeals method to be shorter. You can use LINQ to express the filter, and the ObservableCollection constructor has an overload taking an `IEnumerable<T>`, which could simplify it to:

```
private void FilterMeals(MealCategory category)
{
    var filteredMeals = meals.Where(m => m.Category == category);
    lbxMeals.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Meal>(filteredMeals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnVegetarian_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Filer(MealCategory.Vegatarian).Invoke();
}

private void btnMeat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Filer(MealCategory.Meat).Invoke();
}

private void btnFish_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Filer(MealCategory.Fish).Invoke();
}
public Action Filer(MealCategory mealCategory)
 {
    lbxMeals.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Meal>(meals.Where(m=>m.Category=mealCategory))
  }
```

Comment: This won't compile since you are not returning anything from a non-void method. What's the point with `Action` here, anyway ?

Comment: I think he means `public Action<MealCategory> Filer=new Action<MealCategory>(){mealCategory=> lbxMeals.ItemsSource=....};`

Answer (score 0):

Too cumbersome. You can simply do this:

```
private void btnMeat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lbxMeals.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Meal>(
                              meals.Where(m => m.Category == MealCategory.Meat));
}
```

and of course the same for Vegetarian and Fish.